# Need insight on building a blog with firebase

Tags: html, wordpress, firebase, backend, blogs

Okay. So I've built a couple of websites for people. I'm a front end developer and I've toggled with backed a bit but not much to be confident about it. I am now ready to build my portfolio but it comes in combination with my blog.

I have to options.

1. Static website - I don't have a lot of time. I'm on clock for certain reasons so I'm not sure of this option. However I feel as though it will be easier to add the firebase series I want. Such as firebase hosting,  database, storage and authentication. Also you know how in blogs when your going through their post and you click 'next'and it pops up more blog posts. Can this be done with firebase?
2. WordPress - every person,  even none developers have toggled with WordPress. I'm no expert in it but Im sure it will be much easier to pick up that javascript. Because of time this seems the best option but I'm confused about integration with the services I want. I know that on WordPress I can create a post and it pops it up live. I don't need to create that with firebase? Will I even need firebase database or storage? How would I work with login in and authentication?

Any advice?

Comment: wordpress requires a server which costs money, use Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is simply to build a page about yourself + blog pick the easiest CMS known which is Wordpress, in fact almost every even free template offers just that. The fastest, the simplest and the least time-consuming thing. Firebase is a nice tool rather intended for building applications with data streaming like real time application which is not your goal here. I have both firebase and wordpress projects behind me, and I'm a front end developer as well and with a clear conscience, if you only want to create a blog and your portfolio, don't worry about authentication and possible security, choose Wordpress.

However, if you approach this as a challenge and both the construction of the blog is to be a lesson to you, try one of the available starters for firebase blogs, e.g. https://github.com/NeoWu1216/firebase-blog

the idea of ​​using firebase may seem cool but not for that purpose. Save your time and just install wordpress ;)

Comment: Thanks for that but can i still host the wordpress site on firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress and Firebase do not work well together since Firebase only serves static HTML files and cannot run server-side code. Wordpress is built on PHP which IS server-side. If you want to make a dynamic blog on Firebase you will have to find or create an app that runs the code client-side. Another option is to use a static site generator like Jekyll to create a static site and upload it to Firebase. So unless you know something that I don’t about Wordpress and its compatibility with Firebase, I think you should choose something else like Jekyll